# Cant use a class from import file

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to split a project into multiple files and when I'm trying to import a file I'm getting this warnings/errors

`warning.js:36Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`Menu`.
warning.js:36Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`Menu`.
invariant.js:38 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of`Menu`.(…)`

I tried googling this issue and I saw many posts like this one but I couldn't manage to solve this issue.
here is the Menu.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' 
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Link from 'react-router'

export default class Menu extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="test">Link1</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="test2">Link2</Link></li>
            </ul>
        )
    };
}
```

and here the app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Menu from './Menu'

const Home = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="headerNav">
          <Menu />
        </div>
        <h1>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const RestOf = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<h1>Will it get all the others ?</h1>);
  }
});

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}> 
    <Route path="/" component={Home} > 
      <Route path="*" component={RestOf} />
    </Route> 
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

well, I tried almost everything I found from searching, not sure what I'm missing here tbh .. but I'm really confused from these errors.
p.s I'm really new at React.

something that I've noticed if I'll put the Menu class inside the app.jsx as and defined it as the other classes it will work just fine.

edit: I'm using webpack so compile the react files.

thanks!

Comment: You could try adding the `.jsx` extension when requiring the `Main` component

Comment: I tried, same issue ...

Comment: Maybe you need to add braces around Link in Menu.jsx: `import { Link } from 'react-router'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me looks like the problem is with the `Link` import from `react-router` in the `Menu.jsx` file. It should be like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class Menu extends Component {
```

Please note the `{}`. React router exports an object with a Link key.

In the second file your import looks fine:

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
```

That explains why this worked when you pasted the Menu class in there.

A hint here is the error message:

```
Check the render method of Menu.
```

So you can be sure that the Menu class is being loaded, and the error is in your render function.
If the Menu file wasn't found you would get a message saying that Menu is undefined or something like that.